# How do I protect a question?

Tags: support

Today I got to 15,000 reputation. Neat-o, I got a little notification that I could now protect questions!

Now, let's try this! Go to [any question](https://superuser.com/questions/308771/why-are-we-still-using-cpus-instead-of-gpus), click the "Protect" link.

[image]

… but …

Where is the link for it? Where do I have to look? Needless to say, the [official FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question/52765#52765) doesn't mention where that link is either.

Comment: Your question link is broken BTW.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisF – it doesn't work for any question really, though.

Comment: I like the freehand unhappy face...

Comment: Thanks @studiohack. I was in the middle of preparing spreadsheets, bad idea!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [privilege page](https://superuser.com/privileges/protect-questions) states that the question must be at least a day old. However the screen shot indicates that the question is more than a day old so it should be there.

I've noticed that your rep is *exactly* 15,000. Perhaps there's a bug in that the privilege itself checks for `rep > 15000` while the notification checks for `rep >= 15000`.

Most of the time you'd be **over** the limit rather than **on** the limit so you wouldn't notice the error.

Comment: … who wants to give me a lousy +1 on a question so I can check? :P

Comment: @slhck - there you go. You still won't be able to protect on Meta though.

Comment: Interestingly enough, it works now. Off to file a bug report. Thank you!

Comment: @slhck Perhaps do a rep recalc first :P